# Android Listview Header and Section Month and date list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am a new android developer. I have searched google a lot but I
didn't get the desired result. I also tried my logic but I didn't get it. If any one can help regarding this, I would be thankful.

```
1. My problem is that

    ______________
    November,2012     //This is header 
    ______________
    November 12,2012
    November 15,2012   //This list of date that contain in month
    _____________
    December,2012      //This is header 
    _____________
    December 23,2012
    December 30,2012    //This list of date that contain in month
```

My question is how to get list of items that contain same month and list out of
item within them How can I get this solved? Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: and the question is________?

Comment: plz explain more about your problem

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj i am edited..and  my question how to item same month within date are contain..

Comment: @Arash i have one header(month name) k. now when header name same with list(month name,date) i wanna get them and list out..above..

Comment: do you want filter your list with your header?

Comment: @hsigmond : im not altaf!

Comment: @hsigmond i am not much question asked and this issue also not solved bro.. so i cant accept it..:)

Comment: https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Look for: Sticky Header ListView

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it

create a custom ListView ROW layout file with a Separator view. (a Header TextView)

listview_row_with_separator.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- list Separator TextView Style - the list separator Header-->
   <TextView
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/textview_header_separator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="November, 2012"
        android:visibility="gone"
         />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_row_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="November 12, 2012"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
    </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Importent!** Make sure your list is sorted in some way (on dates)

extend an ArrayAddapter holding "Your_List_Item" 's and implement a populateView(Your_List_Item) that shows a separator if the next list item is not equal the previous list item.

```
public class Your_List_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Your_List_Item> {
private Activity mActivity;
private String mCurrentMonth = "";

public Your_Adapter(Activity activity) {
    super(activity, 0);
      mActivity = activity;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.listview_row_with_separator, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // the (list row) convertView is already inflated, so we can get
        // it from the Tag
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Your_List_Item your_list_item = getItem(position);

    //Check if the next list item is not equal the previous list item.
    if (!mCurrentMonth.equalsIgnoreCase(your_list_item.month.toString())) {
        holder.populateView(your_list_item, true);
        mCurrentMonth = your_list_item.date;
    } else{
        holder.populateView(your_list_item, false);
    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

A ViewHolder class for the adapter displaying the seperator if needed

```
class ViewHolder { 

/********** DECLARES ************/
private TextView textView_row_value;
public TextView textview_header_separator;

public ViewHolder(final View root) {
    /********** INITIALIZES *************/
    textview_header_separator = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textview_header_separator);
    textView_row_value = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textView_row_value);
}

public void populateView(final Your_List_Item your_list_item,final boolean needSeparator) {
    /*
     *  add Separator
     */

    if (needSeparator) {
             //set header text: November, 2012
         textview_header_separator.setText(your_list_item.date);
             textview_header_separator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
             textview_header_separator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    //set row value: November 12, 2012
    textView_row_value.setText(your_list_item.date);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want having your multiple headers in a list and when you click desired header that list subdates under, so you can use expandable ListView but if you want select your Month outside of your list and then matched dates get listed with selected month you can use

```
youradapter.setFilterQueryProvider
```

or you can use textwatcher to filter your list with your desired month