# android display date in header of listview

Tags: android, listview, date

all I need is to display a date on the header of a chat, like whatsapp does.
The screenshot below shows what I want.

I have done all the things, but I still need to display the date in the header of listview.
How to make it?

I have seen this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017742/android-listview-header-and-section-month-and-date-list) and also [this](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)

But in all of those the header is fixed. In my case I have the data coming from a database

Thanks in advance.

Pragna bhatt

[image]

Comment: where is the header? is it near `Whitemans Chat`? also post the layout xml and adapter item xml might be useful

Comment: Have your adapter `getView` to find which view to render. Have some database boolean value `isDate` and if it is true, render this Date view from your `getView` method?

Comment: It is just finding which view to render in `getView` method.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways yo sort a list based on month

1.use comparators to sort the date in a month order.

2.use Calender and Date Function to filter the dates based on a month